# How to design MFC CListCtrl refresh operation?

Tags: c++, mfc, listctrl

I have the following small issue. A pretty old MFC application being ported to C++11. There is a MFC `CListCtrl` in report view the data in which is being refreshed by a separate thread. Either manually or via a timer. The current implementation sets `m_ListCtrl->SetRedraw(FALSE);` deletes all items then populates them back again. This causes a flicker. Also internally the items are sorted via `GetItemData` DWORD, setting each list items new position after sorting. The state of sorting is internal to `CListCtrl`.

What is the best design pattern to add new, update or remove deleted list items after the table has been modified? I am thinking of hashing the contents of the list item row, keeping a separate `vector<RowObject>` table current and after refresh and comparing hashes. Is this a right approach?

Or may be use `m_ListCtrl->SetItemText` on existing items? But how to deal with sorting in this case?

Comment: Set the [LVS_OWNERDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Controls/list-view-window-styles) style and communicate changes in the source data through a call to [CListCtrl::SetItemCountEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class#setitemcountex). No other changes are required. Though synchronizing the data between threads is going to be non-trivial.

Comment: @IInspectable This is great when you have a large amount of data in CListCtrl and you want to update it. And when you want to disable scrolling when items are redrawn so it does not scroll to the top item. In my case CListCtrl is already subclassed with a bunch of SetItemText calls (internal sorting). No to mention that the update thread calls 4 subroutines each inserting own item types in ListView...

Comment: That's called *"strong coupling"*. You are programming against a concrete UI widget implementation. The `LVS_OWNERDATA` style allows you to store your data, irrespective of the UI widget that's eventually going to display it. That's called *"loose coupling"*, and generally leads to more flexible, robust, and maintainable systems. And in this particular case avoids all sorts of visual glitches.